# Molecular Docking Enzyme Inhibitor Biosensor?

Tags: molecular-biology, enzymes

I had some task to study Molecular Docking relations with Biosensor and I am really new with this discipline (beginner). I am docking C60 with Glucose Oxidase and my question is: what would happen if C60 inhibited the active site of enzyme? Can the protein still be used by the biosensor or would it be broken because of the active site used by C60?

Comment: (1) What is C60?; (2) If C60 is an inhibitor of glucose oxidase, the enzyme can be used as a biosensor of glucose in the absence of C60 and, depending on the mechanism and strength of the inhibition, possibly in the presence of C60 (whose concentration must be determined).

Comment: (1)C60 is fullerene nanomaterial; (2)Actually c60 is "mediator" to glucose oxidase in real application biosensor. So in simple ways when glucose oxidase meet the substrate. It will made product which can be detected by c60 and c60 will transfer electron to electrode and convert from chemical to electrical energy. What i confused is how interaction happen between glucose oxidase and c60. If c60 inhibit in competitive then the enzyme cannot be used. Or inhibit in non competitive still enzyme cannot be used.

Comment: The biosensor can be calibrated to account for the inhibition. The sensitivity of the biosensor will be lower due to the inhibition, but how much---that depends on the strength of the inhibition.

Comment: So if i docking with AutoDock Vina and get energy binding (Gibbs's free energy) -12.0 and -8.0. It's mean -8.0 better than -12.0? Because -8.0 have smaller energy binding which made weak inhibition than -12.0?

Comment: Molecular docking energy (score) is not free energy. Free energy can be obtained from molecular dynamics simulations of the enzyme-inhibitor complex, and of the inhibitor alone, in solution (water)---and it's not easy. Yes, the lower the binding free energy, the stronger the binding. But if C60 must bind to glucose oxidase for the biosensor to function there needs to be a proper balance: too weak or too high affinity and the biosensor might be inefficient or insensitive. Complementing the calculations with experimental data is a must.

Comment: Okay thats soo helpful logic, i also read about enzyme immobilization before the enzyme attached to biosensor. Is enzyme immobilization make the enzyme rigid? Which mean non-competitive cannot change its structure?

Comment: It depends on the site of immobilization and the mechanism of the inhibition. For example, the immobilization can be done via a linker with little, if any, effect on the dynamics of the enzyme. In fact, most intracellular enzymes don't float freely in the cytoplasm but are attached to other macromolecules.